# Breezejs Unique Constraint with Delete

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, breeze

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo AS (
  Id int not null primary key,
  YesNo char(1) not null default('N')
)
```

That has the following constraint - "one and only one row may have the Value 'Y'"

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_YesNo] ON [dbo].[Foo]
(
    [YesNo] ASC
)
WHERE ([YesNo]=('Y'))
```

The application code (Breeze JS) enforces that one row is always 'Y'.  So if you Delete the Row with YesNo = 'Y', the BLL sets another Row's YesNo field to be Y.

```
origEntity.entityAspect.setDeleted();
otherEntity.YesNo('Y');
```

When performing the actual DB operations, Breeze is FIRST updating the other row to Y, prior to perfoming the delete of the original.  Which violates the unique constraint.  Is there an easy way to make the DELETE happen first or do I need special server side delete handling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze does not control the order of operations performed on the server. You didn't say what technology you're using on the server but the question tags tell me it is EF and SQL Server. In that case, it is EF that is doing the updates before the delete.

I wish there was a way to tell EF what to do. That is not possible so far as I know.

You can take over and it isn't hard to do so especially if you can isolate this sequence of operations from others.   Take a look at the beforeSave... methods. If you need both parts of the save inside the same transaction (likely), learn how to set up your own ambient transaction so that you can make two calls to EF (or the database directly), one to do the deletes, and the other to do the updates.